# how to populate select tag options from database based on a conditional query using jquery ajax in laravel 9

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-9

This is my first question here so sorry if it was not well structured. Thanks in advance for taking the time to read through my question and please bear with me.

I'm trying to build a page to book appointments for a medical center.

In my blade view I have an Input field of type text a select tag to choose from available sections.

A date picker to choose the date of an appointment and a select tag to choose a time for the appointment.

which I want it to be populated from the database based on the relation between appointment.table and slots.table

where appointments hasMany slots and slots belongs to appointments

my database structure is:

appointments.table migration:

```
    public function up()
    {
        if(!Schema::hasTable('users')){
        Schema::create('appointments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('slot_id');
            $table->string('patient');
            $table->string('section');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->foreign('slot_id')->references('id')->on('slots')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and my time slots table migration:

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('slots', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->time('from');
            $table->time('to');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

my blade view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Add Appointment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>
    <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="post" class="btn btn-primary m-2"> logout </a>
    <form action="/appointments" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            @csrf
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>input patient name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="patient" id="patient" placeholder="patient name..." class="form-control mb-2" required>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>choose the section which the patient will visit</label>
                <select type="text" name="section" id="section" class="form-control mb-2" required>
                    <option value="">Select a Section</option>
                        <option value="heart section">Heart section</option>

                        <option value="bone section">bone section</option>

                        <option value="skin section">skin section</option>

                        <option value="x-ray section">x-ray section</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>set the date and time of the appointment:</label>
                <input type="date" name="date" id="date" class="form-control mb-2" required>
                <select type="time" name="time" id="time" class="form-control mb-2" required>
                    <label>pick a time from availabe times</label>
                    <option value="">choose appointment time</option>
                    @foreach ($slot as $option)
                        <option value={{$option->id}} type="time" id="time" name="time">{{$option->from}} , {{$option->to}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="submit" value="Done" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
                <a href="/appointments" class="btn btn-primary mb-2"> Appointments List</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
    @if(!empty($successMsg))
        <div class="alert alert-success"> {{ $successMsg }}</div>
    @endif
</body>

<script>
    date.min = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#date").click(function(){
    $.get('/addAppointment');
  });
});
</script>

</html>
```

in my blade view I want the select time tag to only show available times per date if not previously booked

in my Controller I have the following function:

```
    public function fetch()
    {
        $carbon = Carbon::today();
        $existing_slot_per_day = Appointment::where('date',$carbon)->pluck('slot_id');

        $slot = Time_slot::whereNotIn('id',$existing_slot_per_day)->get();
        return view('addAppointment',compact('slot'));


    }
```

my route is the following:

```
Route::get('/addAppointment' , \[AppointmentController::class , 'fetch'\]);
```

I guess what I'm trying to accomplish is kind of working, the select time tag stopped showing the booked time but only for the day we are in, but if I choose let's say an appointment after a week from today it won't work

the previously booked time after a week from today is still showing in the select time tag

I am new to jQuery ajax and I'm probably doing something wrong somewhere!

Can you please help, thank you in advance.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience i didn't know how to exactly make the photos i add show without the need to push on a link

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you have to pass date on ajax function as well and use that in controller too.  You will have to change this - $carbon = Carbon::today(); - to incorporate date being passed in ajax request.

Comment: @T.Shah thank you dear sir for your comment! can you please instruct me to how should i accomplish this ?

Comment: @T.Shah i have tried to do as you told me but probably i didn't do it the right way. please provide some instructions if you may .

Comment: Please take a moment to review your spelling.

Comment: @JasonAller I did dear sir but you insist to make spell the word bare wrong for an example , please stop editing my post

Comment: The phrase bare with me means to get undressed together, not bear with me which means please be patient. If that was the only change you objected to you could have just left the rest of the corrections and change it back to bare.

Comment: @JasonAller you are probably right , please forgive my ignorance!

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the value of date clicked while calling your ajax function like this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#date").click(function(){
      var date = $("#date").val();
    $.get('/addAppointment/'+date);
  });
});
</script>
```

For that you have to modify your route.

```
Route::get('/addAppointment/{date}' , \[AppointmentController::class , 'fetch'\]);
```

And then in controller use the date like this -

```
public function fetch($date)
{
    DB::enableQueryLog();
    //$carbon = Carbon::today();
    $carbon = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',  $date);
    $existing_slot_per_day = Appointment::where('date',$carbon)->pluck('slot_id');

    $slot = Time_slot::whereNotIn('id',$existing_slot_per_day)->get();
    $query = DB::getQueryLog();
    dd($query);
    return view('addAppointment',compact('slot'));
}
```

I have not been able to test this.  But this will atleast guide you.

Comment: Thank you dear sir for taking the time to Help, i just applied what you suggested but now I'm getting an error. the error is : $slot is undefined , why did this happen although I'm still passing slot the same way i did before?

Comment: May be slot is empty... The controller is not returning any results.

Comment: I have changed date format, please check now.

Comment: still not working sir, showing the same error : $slot is undefined

Comment: I have enabled query log and echoed query.  This will give you insight into actual query.  Once you know that you will be able to modify your code.  And then you can comment out dd($query).